# Execute report by code and filter values AX 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I Need execute `CustAccountStatementExt` report by code in **AX 2009**, but I need execute this report by some filter for example `CustAccount` field of `CustTable`.

Create a **`Job`** to do this, the report execute OK, but without `CustAccount` filter or any other filter.

***Code:***

```
static void SavePdfFileCustAccountExt(Args _args)
{

    Args               args;
    ReportRun          report;
    CustTable          recCustTable;

    ;

    args         = new Args(reportstr("CustAccountStatementExt"));
    recCustTable = CustTable::find("C000000003");

    args.record(recCustTable);

    report = new ReportRun(args);
    report.setTarget(PrintMedium::Screen);

    report.init();
    report.run();
}
```

Then write this lines but nothing happend.

```
args.lookupRecord(recCustTable);
args.lookupField(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
args.lookupValue(recCustTable.AccountNum);
```

I'm sure I have an error in the code, but I can't find it.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be code in the `init()` method of the report that gets the record from `args` and sets the filters.

Comment: I have solved it differently. But your answer is correct. Thanks